# What is the easiest way to correct a misspelled name on an IRS tax refund?

Tags: united-states, irs

A friend of mine is Egyptian. She received an IRS tax refund for taxes she filed during her time while in the US. Unfortunately she has a rather long name and the IRS tax return misspelled one of her 4 surnames, the last one. Consequently, she cannot get the money transferred to her account in Egypt.

She tried calling the IRS international number but got no where. I did the same and domestic and had the same result. There doesn't seem to be anyway online or over the phone to contact someone.

How can we get this fixed?  What's the best way to reach an IRS represent who can help her with this?

My next best plan is to make an appointment to an IRS place in my local area, go there in person, put her on the phone, and have the person I meet with talk to her, but that's kind of a last resort and I would think there should be an easier way.

Comment: Does the name she wrote on the form match the name on her SSN card?

Comment: Do you mean ITIN? Aliens don't have SSNs.

Comment: And the answer is, yes. It matches on everything she submitted but not on the refund she received.

Comment: I think your approach would be a good start then. Bring photocopies of her passport and the return showing the correct name, and have her ready on the phone to talk to the person.

Comment: That's a great idea. If I layout the comparison before them, they will have an easier time seeing it.